# How to automatically convert "%" and "+" in image urls on upload

Tags: errors, uploads, images, cache, encoding

I mass import products via csv and use this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cache-images/ to download the images to my server.

Problem is some of the image urls have % and + characters in them and I get blank images from these.  I always end up having to set the product images manually.

Can anyone please give me the code to insert inside my plugin or maybe in my function.php?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the plugin [Germanix URL](https://github.com/toscho/Germanix-WordPress-Plugin). It converts image names on upload to save characters (and creates much better permalinks than WP).

Comment: This converts URL slugs and filenames to US-ASCII characters? (plugin description partly german, is that an accurate description?). Looks like a great plugin... :)

Comment: Yes, it does. Originally, I have written the plugin to get a way around WP's broken permalink transliterations which are sometimes plain wrong for German. It is one of the many, many plugins I never found the time to publish on wp.org. The source tells better what it does than the description.

Comment: @toscho, thank you for the great plugin.  I've tested it and notice that it only works on images uploaded from my computer?

Comment: my csv actually looks like this title|description|http://somemerchant.com/product3y%74.jpg|http://somemerchant.com/product.jpg|price which is why I need something to download those images to my server and convert the unwanted characters...please correct me if I'm wrong..thanks again

Comment: @toscho After activating the plugin, my permalink that used to be samplesite.com/this-is-my-product became samplesite.com/this is my product ..which gave me 404 error unless i don't use pretty permalinks, how to fix this please...thanks

Comment: @tosche Please disregard my previous comment, the new permalink only affected my new posts, which I've fixed manually..

Comment: @Mars If you just want to strip these characters use `Germanizer::sanitize_filename_filter( $img_name )`. But if the `%` are part of URL encoded non-ASCII characters use `urldecode()` instead to get the correct paths.

Comment: @t31os I’ve added an English description (and support for Turkish). Is it clear enough now?

Comment: @toscho - Never had a problem with the description, just wanted to be sure the translation was correct. ;)